# Extremely Simple Program Won't Compile

Tags: c++, class, stm32cubeide

Just trying to make an SPI class. Here is my code:

```
#ifndef SRC_SPI_H_
#define SRC_SPI_H_

class SPI {

};

#endif
```

Here are the errors:

`expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token  SPI.h   /ICM_Tester/Core/Src    line 4`

`unknown type name 'class'  SPI.h   /ICM_Tester/Core/Src    line 4`

I have tried rebuilding, and I made sure this is a C++ project. Seems like a compiler issue, but I've been banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out. Please help.

Comment: You are trying to compile this as C, not C++.

Comment: A C++ source file should end in `.cpp`, `.cxx`, `.cc` or one of the other common alternatives btw. For example, GCC decides whether to compile as C or C++ from the file ending by default. I don't know how it interprets `.h` by default, but most likely not as C++ since that is also used in C. Header files are not supposed to be compiled standalone. Then, if the build system doesn't call `g++` specifically, it will be compiled as C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Creating a "C++ project" in STM32CubeIDE apparently isn't enough. I had to manually rename `main.c` -> `main.cpp` and now it works.

Comment: Most multi-language compilers will — by default — treat `*.c` files as C, and `*.cpp` files as C++.  Those compilers usually provide a mechanism to explicitly specify the language and ignore the file extension.  Hard to say from the OP question, since it omitted the most important information relevant to the question:  *what is the compile line?*

Comment: Take a look at this question [C++ class inclusion with the STMCubeIDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76597997/c-class-inclusion-with-the-stmcubeide)